# try to modify a item filed in sharepoint using powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

this is some code I wrote:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$webURL = "http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp"
$lists = "OsEM1","OsEM2","OsEM3","OsEM4"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp"
foreach($list in $lists)
   ... ...
   Write-Host $item["Title"]
   #$item["Item"]=$item["Title"] +" ,"+$webURL+"\"+$filename
   $item["Item"]="$tmpValue"+" ,$item[Title]"   
   $item.Update()
  }
}
}
```

it said: Unable to index into an object of type MicroSoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.
something worong when I change the $item["Item"] value?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons that cause this behavior:

- Your permissions don't match what you need to change an item. If you have PowerShell rights, this is often not the case.
- Your list is somehow corrupted. This could have something to do with site columns, content types, the list itself, or views. If you created and did not update the list schema (definition), it wouldn't let you edit it.
- You don't have AllowUnsafeUpdates set to on for the SPWeb (site) object.

All three of these issues generally have better (matching) error messages but sometimes SharePoint doesn't give you all the information that you need in the error messages.

If you need more details, please ask.